# Unable to load database from local server location in C# Connection String (windows application)

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I'm trying to do application to access the database from local file server, but the connection string does not recognize the server location. This is a windows form application, using sqlite. Kindly help me on this one.

File server location will be like this:

```
\\fileserver\Testdb\maindb.db
```

Code used:

```
string server_database_path = @"\\fileserver\Testdb\maindb.db";
string connection_data = "Data Source=" + server_database_path ;

using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connection_data))
{
    conn.Open();

    SQLiteCommand insert_Rec = new SQLiteCommand(query_text, conn);
    insert_Rec.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Error:

> Unable to open database file

Comment: Have you tried to add `Version=3;` to the connection string.

Comment: `string connection_data = "Data Source=" + server_database_path;`

Comment: @skymon, fixed the typo in submitted code.

Comment: @Marvin Klar I will check and update with your suggestion. Thankyou guys

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I dont think that directly specifying the .db is correct. When using a normal SQL Server I would specify the instance (or just the server hosting it if it was the default instance).

So, your connection string should look something like

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=192.168.0.1; User ID=administrator; Password=YOURPASSWORD"
```

or if you are connecting the machine you are on it should be

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1; User ID=administrator; Password=YOURPASSWORD"
```

You could substitute the 127.0.0.1 for \\localhost

Answer (score 0):

I was confused in doing this, but by changing the slash "\" to "/" it really worked.

When i changed the slash in the path string it started to work fine and everything goes well.

Example: @"//fileserver/Testdb/maindb.db"